# How to get the original background noise in between each piece of the recording in Audacity?

Tags: audacity, background

I have about 100 separate pieces of speech, each selected as the best one and cut out from the recordings where I recorded each piece about 5 times to get 1 good.

Now, the problem is that each piece is cut out from the background noise in the recording, which is much louder than total silence. I already placed each piece to the right spot on the timeline, but before and after each piece, it goes from total silence to my background noise and vice versa.

Since my animation heroes talk with echo, and since there is the background noise while they speak, I can not just cut the noise exactly before and after they speak. I have to find another solution.

I would be very grateful for any input from anyone.

Comment: Do you have an example file?

Comment: I have it ready but I don't know exactly how to upload it...

Comment: Rather than resurrect the background noise you can try to remove it from the speech. Follow this link https://www.izotope.com/en/products/rx/features.html

Answer (score 1):

When recording sound that will be edited like you have, you should always record a minute or so of ***room tone*** aka *presence*. See this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presence_(sound_recording)) article for more.

You use this to replace the silent parts in your new timeline. I'd put clips of room tone on a separate track with slight overlaps with the gaps, so you can crossfade if needed to hide any audible cut points.

You may actually have enough room tone already recorded, in the pauses between takes etc. Scour your original recordings for periods of 'silence'. Those can be used to fill in your gaps.

Comment: If you're concerned about the legwork involved in doing this for so much dialogue, check out RX Ambience Replace which will do this all with a few clicks.